# Unity 5 - Can't edit Cloth constraints

Tags: unity-game-engine, cloth-simulation

Hello I can't edit the constraints on my Cloth component.

Here is what I do:

1. create an empty
2. add Cloth Component
3. add a simple plane as mesh

When I then click on edit constraints the "Edit Constraints" window doesn't show up?!
I am using Unity 5.5.1f1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For me what it works was just go to layout and reset to factory settings the UI and thats it!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29934022)